# IBM MQ and Polling on each cluster node

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

Last year I developed a queue monitor that's using System.Reactive.Linq to check if there was a message on the IBM MQ bus

The code is the following

```
 public class QueueMonitor : IObservable<Message>, IDisposable
{
    private string queueName;
    private readonly MQQueue mqQueue;
    private readonly MQQueueManager queueManager;

    private readonly IDisposable timer;
    private readonly object lockObj = new object();
    private bool isChecking;

    private readonly List<IObserver<Message>> observers;

    public QueueMonitor(MQQueueManager queueManager, string queueName)
    {
        this.queueName = queueName;
        this.queueManager = queueManager;

        observers = new List<IObserver<Message>>();

        mqQueue = queueManager.AccessQueue(queueName,
            MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF // open queue for input
            + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING); // but not if MQM stopping

        timer = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Subscribe(_ =>
        {
            lock (lockObj)
            {
                if (!isChecking)
                {
                    isChecking = true;

                    var mqMsg = new MQMessage();
                    var mqGetMsgOpts = new MQGetMessageOptions {WaitInterval = 1};

                    // 15 second limit for waiting
                    mqGetMsgOpts.Options |= MQC.MQGMO_WAIT;
                    try
                    {
                        mqQueue.Get(mqMsg, mqGetMsgOpts);
                        if (mqMsg.Format.CompareTo(MQC.MQFMT_STRING) == 0)
                        {
                            var text = mqMsg.ReadString(mqMsg.MessageLength);
                            System.Console.WriteLine(text);

                            Message message = new Message { Content = text };
                            foreach (var observer in observers)
                                observer.OnNext(message);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.Console.WriteLine("Non-text message");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (MQException ex)
                    {
                        if ((ex.Message == "MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE"))
                        {
                            //nothing to do, emtpy queue
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //log
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        isChecking = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<Message> observer)
    {
        if (!observers.Contains(observer))
            observers.Add(observer);

        return new Unsubscriber(observers, observer);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        ((IDisposable)mqQueue)?.Dispose();
        ((IDisposable)queueManager)?.Dispose();

        timer?.Dispose();
    }
}

public class Unsubscriber : IDisposable
{
    private readonly List<IObserver<Message>> _observers;
    private readonly IObserver<Message> _observer;

    public Unsubscriber(List<IObserver<Message>> observers, IObserver<Message> observer)
    {
        this._observers = observers;
        this._observer = observer;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_observer != null) _observers.Remove(_observer);
    }
}
```

This worked for almost a year, but now 2 things need to be fixed, and hope you can help me getting it done right.

1) If the IBMMQ is restarted, currently the QueueMonitor doesn't get new incoming message, it needs to be re-started.

How should I handle it? I don't know if there's a restart of the IBM MQ on the Monitor side.

2) More complicated. We're migrating to a new balanced IBMMQ cluster. It has 4 active nodes configured as active. They are all behind a load balancer so when I put a message on the bus I send it to a single address.

For sending a message, it's simple. The problem I've is when I need to read from the queue. Since there're 4 different IBMMQ nodes, with 4 IPs. How do I know that a message has been sent on the bus? I can't simply listen on the balancer since it won't have a notification. Should I ping the 4 nodes?

The balancer is netscaler.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the logic where you are catching `MQException` , do you get events when it's not a `MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE`, but some other error indicating that MQ is restarting or not available?

Comment: yes, I found that it throws a MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN, now I check if I can perform a reconnect. Thanks

Comment: I would suggest you monitor each of the 4 instances individually not using the LB address.

Comment: @JoshMc monitoring the 4 istances means that in my queueMonitor class I have to register those 4 ip address and their configuration... I think that the c# classes have the same methods. can you please tell me to which class do you refer to?

Comment: Sorry auto correct on my phone above, please see this comment: IBM has two Java API interfaces.  The one you show in your code is the IBM MQ Classes for Java API.  This has been stabilized at the IBM MQ v8.0 level or code, this was announced when IBM MQ v9.0 was released.  IBM even since 7.0 had not enhanced the IBM MQ Classes for Java API with newer features such as Auto Reconnect.  IBM MQ Classes for JMS are preferred since they are not stabilized and they do have the auto-reconnect feature.

Comment: You mentioned C# in your comments, both the normal IBM MQ .Net classes (Managed or Unmanaged) and the XMS.NET (Managed or Unmanaged) support reconnect as well.

Comment: You would have to directly connect to each of the four queue managers if they are all active at the same time since you would not as you mentioned "know" which queue manager a message was sent to.

Comment: ok for connecting to all the 4 nodes (I suspected so), for reconnect I'm trying but I still got error...I'll update you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IBM MQ cluster, you can connect to any queue manager in the cluster and push a message,  MQ ensures that the message reaches to its destination queue even if the queue wasn't locally defined on the queue manager you connected to while performing the put action. While performing a get message action by an application from a queue, you have to connect to the queue manager which locally has the destination queue defined to pick the message. So, yes in your case you'll have to connect to each individual 4 queue managers to pick message.

Since you are migrating to new MQ architecture, I would suggest you to look at IBM MQ v9.1 Advanced which has a concept of RDQM. RDQM (replicated data queue manager) is a high availability solution that is available on Linux platforms as of now.

Find below the link:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q130280_.htm